# Check if data sent from Flex to Java server is zipped or not

Tags: java, apache-flex, jboss, wireshark, remoteobject

I want to analyse if the XML I send from my client Flex to my Java using remoteObject is compressed or not.
for this, I'm using Wireshark, but it can't get packets in the localhost (windows vista)
how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to capture in localhost : [Caputre using Ethereal/Wireshark](http://www.lemmy.fr/capturer-localhost-sous-windows-avec-ethereal-wireshark.html)
sorry it's in french.

for me, I used an other computer as a server, and analyse all the trafic between my computer and the server.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler will probably work better for you than Wireshark because you can decrypt your https traffic if you install its cert as trusted locally.  You didn't mention https as a factor, but if it is Wireshark won't do it as far as I know.

You can also direct your service calls to your computer's ip instead of localhost.  Example:  localhost goes to 127.0.0.1, instead route your requests to the ip you get when you issue an ipconfig /all.  You can hack your hosts file to route something to that ip.

Not sure if this always works in Wireshark, but it does in Fiddler for sure.